# Update Git submodule to latest commit on origin

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-pull

I have a project with a Git submodule. It is from an ssh://... URL, and is on commit A. Commit B has been pushed to that URL, and I want the submodule to retrieve the commit, and change to it.

Now, my understanding is that `git submodule update` should do this, but it doesn't. It doesn't do anything (no output, success exit code). Here's an example:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /.../foo/.git/
$ git submodule add ssh://user@host/git/mod mod
Cloning into mod...
user@host's password: hunter2
remote: Counting objects: 131, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (115/115), done.
remote: Total 131 (delta 54), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (131/131), 16.16 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (54/54), done.
$ git commit -m "Hello world."
[master (root-commit) 565b235] Hello world.
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 mod
# At this point, ssh://user@host/git/mod changes; submodule needs to change too.
$ git submodule init
Submodule 'mod' (ssh://user@host/git/mod) registered for path 'mod'
$ git submodule update
$ git submodule sync
Synchronizing submodule url for 'mod'
$ git submodule update
$ man git-submodule 
$ git submodule update --rebase
$ git submodule update
$ echo $?
0
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git submodule update mod
$ ...
```

I've also tried `git fetch mod`, which appears to do a fetch (but can't possibly, because it's not prompting for a password!), but `git log` and `git show` deny the existence of new commits. Thus far I've just been `rm`-ing the module and re-adding it, but this is both wrong in principle and tedious in practice.

Comment: David Z's answer seems like the better way of doing this - now that Git has the functionality you need built in via the `--remote` option, perhaps it would be useful to mark that as the accepted answer rather than the "by hand" approach in Jason's answer?

Comment: I'm agreeing highly with @MarkAmery. While Jason gave a working solution, it isn't the intended way to do it, as it leaves the submodule's commit pointer at the wrong commit identifier. The new `--remote` is definitively a better solution at this point in time, and since this question has been linked to from a Github Gist about submodules, I feel it would be better for incoming readers to see the new answer.

Comment: Nice touch with the `hunter2` password :o)

Answer (score 1860, accepted):

The [`git submodule update`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) command actually tells Git that you want your submodules to each check out the commit already specified in the index of the superproject. If you want to *update* your submodules to the latest commit available from their remote, you will need to do this directly in the submodules.

So in summary:

```sh
# Get the submodule initially
git submodule add ssh://bla submodule_dir
git submodule init

# Time passes, submodule upstream is updated
# and you now want to update

# Change to the submodule directory
cd submodule_dir

# Checkout desired branch
git checkout master

# Update
git pull

# Get back to your project root
cd ..

# Now the submodules are in the state you want, so
git commit -am "Pulled down update to submodule_dir"
```

Or, if you're a busy person:

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

Comment: `git submodule foreach git pull`

Comment: @MathiasBynens: You have to check out a branch on the submodule since it is in a detached state by default.

Comment: @Nicklas In that case, use `git submodule foreach git pull origin master`.

Comment: At this point, with all these corrections to the corrections, I need someone to write an explanatory blog post and point me there. Please.

Comment: the key to this answer is making sure you commit within your own branch/repo so that your ref gets updated to where the latest submodule commit is (at least that is my understanding)

Comment: I think the solution is correct, but explanation of what `git submodule update` does is wrong. On an initialized submodule, the command will checkout the commit of the submodule "remembered" by the parent.

Comment: minor improvement to the 'foreach' approach - you may want to add --recursive in there in case you have submodules within submodules. so:
`git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master`.

Comment: What if each git submodule has a different default branch?

Comment: `git add ...` missing before `git commit ...`?

Comment: @Abdull The `-a` switch for `git commit` "Tell[s] the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected."

Comment: @Jason Why do you need `git submodule init` after the `git submodule add`. When I `git submodule add` it seems to clone the submodule automatically.

Comment: `git submodule update --remote` will update the local master of all submodules with their respective remote master

Comment: I would suggest `cd -` instead of `cd ..` to make sure you are back in the root project and not in the parent folder.

Comment: NOTE: Because of the recent default branch name change (master -> main), you'll need to update the commands accordingly.

Comment: I found I needed to do `git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -xfd && git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard`. (I don't know if both of those were needed or just the second part.)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get no errors, but also git says there is nothing to commit. Still stuck with a dirty submodule commit.

Answer (score 668):

Git 1.8.2 features a new option, `--remote`, that will enable exactly this behavior. Running

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

will fetch the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, merge them in, and check out the latest revision of the submodule. As [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) puts it:

> #### --remote
>
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.

This is equivalent to running `git pull <remote> <default_branch>` (usually `git pull origin master` or `git pull origin main`) in each submodule, which is generally exactly what you want.

Comment: *"equivalent to running `git pull` in each submodule"* To clarify, there is no difference (from the user's perspective) between your answer and `git submodule foreach git pull`?

Comment: @Dennis it does essentially the same thing, but I'm not sure if the functionality is _exactly_ the same. There might be some minor differences that I don't know about, e.g. in the way the two commands respond to some configuration setting.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 10,000X. Why isn't this shown in git's documentation anywhere? Huge oversight.

Comment: For me they actually differed quite significantly; `foreach git pull` only checked them out, but did not update the pointer of the main repo to point to the newer commit of the submodule. Only with `--remote` it made it point to the latest commit.

Comment: If it is equivalent to `git pull`, then isn't `--merge` the default using just `--remote`?

Comment: why the --merge option? What difference does it makes?

Comment: Anybody know why I get the error: "fatal: destination path 'path/to/submodule' already exists and is not an empty directory"?

Comment: This _is_ mentioned in the Pro Git book, but it fails for us with a permission error when run from Jenkins.

Comment: Use it with `-j` to update submodules in parallel ex. '-j8' to create up to 8 updating jobs.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer, but after working with git submodules for 2 days (not my own choice) I'd recommend staying far away from it. The process of working with git submodules was (for me at least) extremely painful and I think there are simpler options.

Comment: you saved my day. This was the only option working on gitlab-ci

Comment: Nowadys with a mixture of repos using a `master` or a `main` branch the `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` will fail.

Therefore `git submodule update --remote` is the better solution.

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of `--merge`? It seems to me the best answer is `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote`, with*out* the `--merge` option.

Comment: As is frequently the case, this is a complicated topic. [Here are my summary and conclusions thus far.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74470585/4561887)

Comment: @GabrielStaples Can I ask, why did you change the `git pull` command to include an explicit remote and branch? Does that make a difference in what the command does?

Comment: (1/4) @DavidZ, a lot of people think that `git submodule foreach git pull` and `git submodule update --remote` are the same thing, with the latter simply being the newer command. _They aren't_ the same thing, however. `git submodule foreach git pull` will _fail under multiple circumstances_ for which `git submodule update --remote` works just fine! If your submodule points to a commit hash that doesn't have a branch pointing to it, which is frequently the case in real-life development where you want a particular version of the submodule for your outer repo, then that submodule...

Comment: (2/4)...is in a detached HEAD state. In this case, `git submodule foreach git pull` fails to run `git pull` on that submodule since a detached HEAD cannot have an upstream branch. `git submodule update --remote`, however, _works just fine!_ It appears to call `git pull origin main` on that submodule if `origin` is the default remote and `main` is the default branch on that default remote, or `git pull origin master`, for instance, if `origin` is the default remote but `master` is the default branch.

Comment: (3/4) Furthemore, `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` will even fail in many cases where `git submodule update --remote` works just fine, since many submodules use `master` as the default branch, and many other submodules use `main` as the default branch since GitHub changed from `master` to `main` recently in order to get away from terms related to slavery in the United States ("master" and "slave").

Comment: (4/4) So, I added the explicit remote and branch to make it more clear that they are frequently needed, and to remind people that `git pull` is frequently not enough, and `git pull origin master` may not work, and `git pull origin main` may work when the former doesn't, but also may not even work, and that _none_ of them by themselves are the same as `git submodule update --remote`, since that latter command is smart enough to just do `git pull <default_remote> <default_branch>` for you for each submodule, apparently adjusting the remote and branch as necessary for each submodule.

Comment: @DavidZ, I just updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74470585/4561887) with my 4 comments above plus more info.

Answer (score 168):

In your project parent directory, run:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Or if you have recursive submodules run:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Sometimes this still doesn't work, because somehow you have local changes in the local submodule directory while the submodule is being updated.

Most of the time the local change might not be the one you want to commit. It can happen due to a file deletion in your submodule, etc. If so, do a reset in your local submodule directory and in your project parent directory, run again:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: this is the true answer. can i push it to my remote repository somehow?

Comment: This works for new submodules! I could update all the others but the folder of new submodules would remain empty until I ran this command.

Comment: It doesn't pull changes for existing submodules

Comment: This will clone the submodules, but only to the commit specified in the main repo. You need to `cd` into the submodule folder and run `git pull origin <branch_name>` to get the latest commit, after running `git submodule update --init`

Answer (score 88):

Your main project points to a particular commit that the submodule should be at. `git submodule update` tries to check out that commit in each submodule that has been initialized. The submodule is really an independent repository - just creating a new commit in the submodule and pushing that isn't enough. You also need to explicitly add the new version of the submodule in the main project.

So, in your case, you should find the right commit in the submodule - let's assume that's the tip of `master`:

```
cd mod
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Now go back to the main project, stage the submodule and commit that:

```
cd ..
git add mod
git commit -m "Updating the submodule 'mod' to the latest version"
```

Now push your new version of the main project:

```
git push origin master
```

From this point on, if anyone else updates their main project, then `git submodule update` for them will update the submodule, assuming it's been initialized.

Answer (score 31):

Note, while the modern form of updating submodule commits would be:

```
git submodule update --recursive --remote --force
```

See [Gabriel Staples](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4561887/gabriel-staples)'s answer for an alternative take, *not* using `--merge --force`.

The [`--force` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--filterltfilterspecgt--ltpathgt82308203) allows for the checkout to take place even if the commit specified in the index of the containing repository already matches the commit checked out in the submodule.

The `--merge` option seems not necessary in this case: "the commit recorded in the superproject will be merged into the current branch in the submodule."

---

The older form was:

```
git submodule foreach --quiet git pull --quiet origin
```

Except... this second form is not really "quiet".

See [commit a282f5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a282f5a90613de5f4b449749ea8738ac20872271) (12 Apr 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f1c9f6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1c9f6ce38445c7cba7dd5b2a8c329c8fff90993), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `submodule foreach`: fix "`<command> --quiet`" not being respected

> Robin reported that
>
> ```
> git submodule foreach --quiet git pull --quiet origin
> ```
>
> is not really quiet anymore.
> It should be quiet before [fc1b924](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc1b9243cd5d51ae455272f1f953d4002294edee) (`submodule`: port `submodule` subcommand '`foreach`' from shell to C, 2018-05-10,  Git v2.19.0-rc0) because `parseopt` can't accidentally eat options then.
>
> "`git pull`" behaves as if `--quiet` is not given.
>
> This happens because `parseopt` in `submodule--helper` will try to parse
> both `--quiet` options as if they are foreach's options, not `git-pull`'s.
> The parsed options are removed from the command line. So when we do
> pull later, we execute just this
>
> ```
> git pull origin
> ```
>
> When calling submodule helper, adding "`--`" in front of "`git pull`" will
> stop `parseopt` for parsing options that do not really belong to
> `submodule--helper foreach`.
>
> `PARSE_OPT_KEEP_UNKNOWN` is removed as a safety measure. `parseopt` should
> never see unknown options or something has gone wrong. There are also
> a couple usage string update while I'm looking at them.
>
> While at it, I also add "`--`" to other subcommands that pass "`$@`" to
> `submodule--helper`. "`$@`" in these cases are paths and less likely to be
> `--something-like-this`.
> But the point still stands, `git-submodule` has parsed and classified what are options, what are paths.
> `submodule--helper` should never consider paths passed by `git-submodule` to be options even if they look like one.

---

And Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) fixes another issue: "`git submodule foreach`" did not protect command line options passed to the command to be run in each submodule correctly, when the "`--recursive`" option was in use.

See [commit 30db18b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30db18b148c4951deb2c870b5243fb5b18ecb5ed) (24 Jun 2019) by [Morian Sonnet (`momoson`)](https://github.com/momoson).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 968eecb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/968eecbd01e06aa8cae6c7fd8bf0a7b9bbd3b1fc), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `submodule foreach`: fix recursion of options

> Calling:
>
> ```
> git submodule foreach --recursive <subcommand> --<option>
> ```
>
> leads to an error stating that the option `--<option>` is unknown to
> `submodule--helper`.
> That is of course only, when `<option>` is not a valid option for `git submodule foreach`.
>
> The reason for this is, that above call is internally translated into a
> call to submodule--helper:
>
> ```
> git submodule--helper foreach --recursive \
>    -- <subcommand> --<option>
> ```
>
> This call starts by executing the subcommand with its option inside the
> first level submodule and continues by calling the next iteration of
> the `submodule foreach` call
>
> ```
> git --super-prefix <submodulepath> submodule--helper \
>   foreach --recursive <subcommand> --<option>
> ```
>
> inside the first level submodule. Note that the double dash in front of
> the subcommand is missing.
>
> This problem starts to arise only recently, as the `PARSE_OPT_KEEP_UNKNOWN` flag for the argument parsing of `git submodule foreach` was removed in commit [a282f5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a282f5a90613de5f4b449749ea8738ac20872271).
> Hence, the unknown option is complained about now, as the argument parsing is not properly ended by the double dash.
>
> This commit fixes the problem by adding the double dash in front of the subcommand during the recursion.

---

Note that, before Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git submodule update --quiet`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/300cd14ee92eaa0e56688078e967402371488013/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L266)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---quiet))</sup> did not squelch underlying "rebase" and "pull" commands.

See [commit 3ad0401](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ad0401e9e6d3e243a21a3f376e36453572dcf0d) (30 Sep 2020) by [Theodore Dubois (`tbodt`)](https://github.com/tbodt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 300cd14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/300cd14ee92eaa0e56688078e967402371488013), 05 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`submodule update`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ad0401e9e6d3e243a21a3f376e36453572dcf0d): silence underlying merge/rebase with "`--quiet`"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Theodore Dubois</sup>

> Commands such as
>
> ```
> $ git pull --rebase --recurse-submodules --quiet
> ```
>
> produce non-quiet output from the merge or rebase.
> Pass the `--quiet` option down when invoking "`rebase`" and "`merge`".
>
> Also fix the parsing of [`git submodule update`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3ad0401e9e6d3e243a21a3f376e36453572dcf0d/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L136)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N%7C--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f%7C--force--checkout%7C--rebase%7C--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--ltpathgt...))</sup> -v.
>
> When [e84c3cf3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e84c3cf3dc3c3140d317f7ed0b18768adbec0401) ("`git-submodule.sh`: accept verbose flag in `cmd_update` to be non-quiet", 2018-08-14, Git v2.19.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce9c6a3c78bc2e2ebbe5f3351a2623d6101985f8)) taught "[`git submodule update`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3ad0401e9e6d3e243a21a3f376e36453572dcf0d/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L136)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N%7C--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f%7C--force--checkout%7C--rebase%7C--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--ltpathgt...))</sup> to take "`--quiet`", it apparently did not know how `${GIT_QUIET`:+--quiet} works, and reviewers seem to have missed that setting the variable to "0", rather than unsetting it, still results in "`--quiet`" being passed to underlying commands.

---

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), `git-submodule.sh` is prepared to be turned into a builtin, meaning the `submodule--helper` which has issues described above is being faded out.

See [commit 5b893f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b893f7d81eb7feb43662ed8663e2af76a76b4c8), [commit 2eec463](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2eec463739745d2110aa5462ba9547fa8d255ebb), [commit 8f12108](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f12108c2951cdfa181d6be66b6def28cd007bdd), [commit 36d4516](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36d45163b6de05886c2c6feb2e626ce423b96b3b), [commit 6e556c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e556c412e9283cfa9f9be4bfe4e9c813a53bf52), [commit 0d68ee7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d68ee723e54330138450f29e358e5ebe1a47aa0), [commit d9c7f69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9c7f69aaa6b001949e9d2b693c22c595cc9d0d6), [commit da3aae9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da3aae9e8476af3b23363d39dba86b679c14a498), [commit 757d092](https://github.com/git/git/commit/757d0927976cf9d59a050f8f9ce1fe54d4dff653), [commit 960fad9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/960fad98e8a8d4c123bb5040f616f856cb9925ea), [commit 8577525](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85775255f18e0a6a6b2e65394bc18ec440dba99d) (28 Jun 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit b788fc6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b788fc671bf1862a72f9fe7256affd7d152b8a6f) (28 Jun 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 361cbe6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/361cbe6d6d24142d4b773f4077c07e25687680d6), 14 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-submodule.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2eec463739745d2110aa5462ba9547fa8d255ebb): use "`$quiet`", not "`$GIT_QUIET"`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Remove the use of the `"$GIT_QUIET"` variable in favor of our own "`$quiet`", ever since [b3c5f5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3c5f5cb04854b56b39a40696c366053c8f09b58) ("`submodule`: move core `cmd_update()` logic to C", 2022-03-15, Git v2.36.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf0e875cd823b6e2a17f387a9c83ec7dd96aac00)) we have not used the "say" function in `git-sh-setup.sh`, which is the only thing that's affected by using "`GIT_QUIET"`.
>
> We still want to support `--quiet` for our own use though, but let's use our own variable for that.
> Now it's obvious that we only care about passing "`--quiet`" to `git submodule--helper`, and not to change the output of any "`say`" invocation.

Comment: In the cmd `git submodule update --recursive --remote --merge --force`, `--force` seems to be dangerous by throwing away local changes in the submodule, and `--merge` bewilders me. I can't figure out what it's doing, other than keeping my submodule from actually changing when I cd into it to see if it changed, after running the cmd. Can you please verify my understanding on `--force`, and help me understand the nuances of `--merge`?

Comment: As is frequently the case, this is a complicated topic. [Here are my summary and conclusions thus far.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74470585/4561887)

Comment: @GabrielStaples Good point. I have removed the `--merge` option (kept the `--force` one, with documentation), and referenced your own answer (upvoted).

Answer (score 30):

It seems like two different scenarios are being mixed together in this discussion:

**Scenario 1**

Using my parent repository's pointers to submodules, I want to check out the commit in each submodule that the parent repository is pointing to, possibly after first iterating through all submodules and updating/pulling these from remote.

This is, as pointed out, done with

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin BRANCH
git submodule update
```

**Scenario 2, which I think is what OP is aiming at**

New stuff has happened in one or more submodules, and I want to 1) pull these changes and 2) update the parent repository to point to the HEAD (latest) commit of this/these submodules.

This would be done by

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin BRANCH
git add module_1_name
git add module_2_name
......
git add module_n_name
git push origin BRANCH
```

Not very practical, since you would have to hardcode n paths to all n submodules in e.g. a script to update the parent repository's commit pointers.

It would be cool to have an automated iteration through each submodule, updating the parent repository pointer (using `git add`) to point to the head of the submodule(s).

For this, I made this small Bash script:

***git-update-submodules.sh***

```bash
#!/bin/bash

APP_PATH=$1
shift

if [ -z $APP_PATH ]; then
  echo "Missing 1st argument: should be path to folder of a git repo";
  exit 1;
fi

BRANCH=$1
shift

if [ -z $BRANCH ]; then
  echo "Missing 2nd argument (branch name)";
  exit 1;
fi

echo "Working in: $APP_PATH"
cd $APP_PATH

git checkout $BRANCH && git pull --ff origin $BRANCH

git submodule sync
git submodule init
git submodule update
git submodule foreach "(git checkout $BRANCH && git pull --ff origin $BRANCH && git push origin $BRANCH) || true"

for i in $(git submodule foreach --quiet 'echo $path')
do
  echo "Adding $i to root repo"
  git add "$i"
done

git commit -m "Updated $BRANCH branch of deployment repo to point to latest head of submodules"
git push origin $BRANCH
```

To run it, execute

```
git-update-submodules.sh /path/to/base/repo BRANCH_NAME
```

**Elaboration**

First of all, I assume that the branch with name $BRANCH (second argument) exists in all repositories. Feel free to make this even more complex.

The first couple of sections is some checking that the arguments are there. Then I pull the parent repository's latest stuff (I prefer to use --ff (fast-forwarding) whenever I'm just doing pulls. I have rebase off, BTW).

```bash
git checkout $BRANCH && git pull --ff origin $BRANCH
```

Then some submodule initializing, might be necessary, if new submodules have been added or are not initialized yet:

```bash
git submodule sync
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Then I update/pull all submodules:

```bash
git submodule foreach "(git checkout $BRANCH && git pull --ff origin $BRANCH && git push origin $BRANCH) || true"
```

Notice a few things: First of all, I'm chaining some Git commands using `&&` - meaning previous command must execute without error.

After a possible successful pull (if new stuff was found on the remote), I do a push to ensure that a possible merge-commit is not left behind on the client. Again, it only happens *if* a pull actually brought in new stuff.

Finally, the final `|| true` is ensuring that script continues on errors. To make this work, everything in the iteration must be wrapped in the double-quotes and the Git commands are wrapped in parentheses (operator precedence).

**My favourite part:**

```bash
for i in $(git submodule foreach --quiet 'echo $path')
do
  echo "Adding $i to root repo"
  git add "$i"
done
```

Iterate all submodules - with `--quiet`, which removes the 'Entering MODULE_PATH' output. Using `'echo $path'` (must be in single-quotes), the path to the submodule gets written to output.

This list of relative submodule paths is captured in an array (`$(...)`) - finally iterate this and do `git add $i` to update the parent repository.

Finally, a commit with some message explaining that the parent repository was updated. This commit will be ignored by default, if nothing was done. Push this to origin, and you're done.

I have a script running this in a [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) job that chains to a scheduled automated deployment afterwards, and it works like a charm.

I hope this will be of help to someone.

Comment: !@#$% SO

We're using scripts akin to yours; one note:

Instead of

```
git submodule foreach --quiet 'echo $path'
```

we use

```
git submodule foreach --recursive --quiet pwd
```

inside the for loops. The `pwd` command prints the proper 'absolute path' for each submodule present; `--recursive` ensures we visit *all* submodules, including the submodules-within-submodules-... that may be present in a large project.

Both methods cause trouble with directories which include spaces, e.g. `/c/Users/Ger/Project\ Files/...` hence policy is to *never* use whitespace anywhere in our projects.

Comment: This is nice, and you're right that there's a misunderstand in some answers about what the question even is, but as pointed out by David Z's excellent answer, your script is unnecessary since the functionality has been built into Git since mid-2013 when they added the `--remote` option. `git submodule update --remote` behaves approximately the way that your script does.

Comment: @GerHobbelt Thanks. You are right, we have only 1 level of submodules, so I never thought to make it recursive. I won't update the script, before I've had a chance to verify it works as expected, but definitely my script would ingore sub-sub-modules. As to spaces in folders, this definitely sounds like something to avoid! :S

Comment: @MarkAmery Thanks for your feedback. I see 1 issue, however: not by-argument being able to specify branch for submodules. From git manual: `The remote branch used defaults to master, but the branch name may be overridden by setting the submodule.<name>.branch option in either .gitmodules or .git/config (with .git/config taking precedence).` I don't want to edit .gitmodules nor .git/config every time I want to do this to another branch than master. But maybe I have missed something? Also, the method seems to enforce recursive merges (thus missing the possibility of a fast-forward).

Comment: Last thing: I tried @DavidZ's method, and it doesn't seem to do the exact thing, I set out to do (and which op was asking about): Adding the HEAD commit of submodules to parent (i.e. "updating the pointer"). It does, however, seem to do the sole job very well (and faster) of fetching and merging latest changes in all submodules. Alas, by default only from master branch (unless you edit the .gitmodules file (see above)).

Comment: @GerHobbelt `git submodule foreach --quiet "printf '%q\n' \"\$(pwd)\""` may help with paths that include spaces and other special characters; manual `%q` options `man --pager='less -p " %q "' printf` states _"ARGUMENT is printed in a format that can be reused as  shell  input, escaping  non-printable  characters with the proposed POSIX $'' syn‐tax"_... eg. `printf '%q\n' "/foo bar/path"` results in `/foo\ bar/path` being output.

Answer (score 23):

Plain and simple, to fetch the submodules:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And now proceed updating them to the latest master branch (for example):

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 13):

### How to update all git submodules in a repo (two ways to do two *very different* things!)

### Quick summary

```bash
# Option 1: as a **user** of the outer repo, pull the latest changes of the
# sub-repos as previously specified (pointed to as commit hashes) by developers
# of this outer repo.
# - This recursively updates all git submodules to their commit hash pointers as
#   currently committed in the outer repo.
git submodule update --init --recursive

# Option 2. As a **developer** of the outer repo, update all subrepos to force
# them each to pull the latest changes from their respective upstreams (ex: via
# `git pull origin main` or `git pull origin master`, or similar, for each
# sub-repo). 
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
#
# For just Option 2 above: now add and commit these subrepo changes 
# you just pulled
git add -A
git commit -m "Update all subrepos to their latest upstream changes"
```

### Details

1. Option 1: as a *user* of the outer repo, trying to get all submodules into the state intended by the developers of the outer repo:

   ```bash
   git submodule update --init --recursive
   ```
2. Option 2: as a *developer* of the outer repo, trying to update all submodules to the latest commit pushed to the default branch of each of their remote repos (ie: update all subrepos to the latest state intended by the developers of each subrepo):

   ```bash
   git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
   ```

   ...in place of using `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master` or `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin main`.

It seems to me that the best answer for both options above is to *not* use the `--merge` and `--force` options I see in some other answers.

Explanation of the options used above:

- the `--init` part above initializes the submodule in case you just cloned the repo and haven't done that yet
- `--recursive` does this for submodules within submodules, recursively down forever
- and `--remote` says to update the submodule to the latest commit on the default branch on the default remote for the submodule. It is like doing `git pull origin master` or `git pull origin main` in most cases, for example, for each submodule. If you want to update to the commit specified by the outer-most repo (super repo) instead, leave `--remote` off.

### `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull` (don't use this--it frequently fails) vs `git submodule update --recursive --remote` (use this!--it always works)

I left the following comments [under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21195182/4561887). I think they are important so I am putting them in my answer too.

Basically, for some situations, `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull` might work. For others, `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master` might be what you need instead. For others, `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin main` might be what you need. And for others still, *none* of those might work! You might need `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull upstream develop`, for instance. OR, even worse, there might not be *any* `git submodule foreach` command which works for your outer repo, as each submodule might require a different command to update itself from its default remote and default branch. In **all** cases I can find, however, this **does** work, including for **all** cases you might use one of the several `git submodule foreach` commands I just presented above. So, use this instead:

```bash
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

Anyway, here are my several comments about that [under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21195182/4561887):

> (1/4) @DavidZ, a lot of people think that `git submodule foreach git pull` and `git submodule update --remote` are the same thing, with the latter simply being the newer command. *They aren't* the same thing, however. `git submodule foreach git pull` will *fail under multiple circumstances* for which `git submodule update --remote` works just fine! If your submodule points to a commit hash that doesn't have a branch pointing to it, which is frequently the case in real-life development where you want a particular version of the submodule for your outer repo, then that submodule...
>
> (2/4)...is in a detached HEAD state. In this case, `git submodule foreach git pull` fails to run `git pull` on that submodule since a detached HEAD cannot have an upstream branch. `git submodule update --remote`, however, *works just fine!* It appears to call `git pull origin main` on that submodule if `origin` is the default remote and `main` is the default branch on that default remote, or `git pull origin master`, for instance, if `origin` is the default remote but `master` is the default branch.
>
> (3/4) Furthemore, `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` will even fail in many cases where `git submodule update --remote` works just fine, since many submodules use `master` as the default branch, and many other submodules use `main` as the default branch since GitHub changed from `master` to `main` recently in order to get away from terms related to slavery in the United States ("master" and "slave").
>
> (4/4) So, I added the explicit remote and branch to make it more clear that they are frequently needed, and to remind people that `git pull` is frequently not enough, and `git pull origin master` may not work, and `git pull origin main` may work when the former doesn't, but also may not even work, and that *none* of them by themselves are the same as `git submodule update --remote`, since that latter command is smart enough to just do `git pull <default_remote> <default_branch>` for you for each submodule, apparently adjusting the remote and branch as necessary for each submodule.

### Related, & other research

1. My general `git submodule` notes: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles#git-submodules-and-git-lfs-how-to-clone-this-repo-and-all-git-submodules-and-git-lfs-files
2. How to find the primary branch of a repo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384283/4561887
3. How to update each subrepo by running a custom command in it via `git submodule foreach <cmd>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744725/4561887
4. `man git submodule` - then search for `foreach`, `--remote`, etc.
5. My answer on [How to resolve conflicts with git submodules, in your outer repo containing them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75488684/4561887)

Comment: Thank you for all the additional details!

Answer (score 11):

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

This will pull all the latest commits.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me to update to the latest commits

`git submodule update --recursive --remote --init`

Comment: This question already has a lot of similar, though not identical, answers. It would help if you could explain how yours improves on what's been said here already.

Answer (score 4):

@Jason is correct in a way but not entirely.

> update
>
> Update the registered submodules,
>   i.e. clone missing submodules and
>   checkout the commit specified in the
>   index of the containing repository.
>   This will make the submodules HEAD be
>   detached unless --rebase or --merge is
>   specified or the key
>   submodule.$name.update is set to
>   rebase or merge.

So, `git submodule update` does checkout, but it is to the commit in the index of the containing repository. It does not yet know of the new commit upstream at all. So go to your submodule, get the commit you want and commit the updated submodule state in the main repository and then do the `git submodule update`.

Comment: It seems that if I move the submodule to a different commit, and then run `git submodule update`, update will move the submodule to the commit that is specified in the current HEAD of the superproject. (whatever the most recent commit in the superproject says the subproject should be at — this behavior, after the explanation in Jason's post, seems logical to me) It also appears to fetch, but only in the case that the subproject is on the wrong commit, which was adding to my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I wanted `git` to update to the latest and at the same time re-populate any missing files.

The following restored the missing files (thanks to `--force` which doesn't seem to have been mentioned here), but it didn't pull any new commits:

`git submodule update --init --recursive --force`

This did:

`git submodule update --recursive --remote --merge --force`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the host branch, make this:

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

It will get a branch of the main Git repository and then for each submodule will make a pull of the same branch.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to checkout `master` branch for each submodule -- you can use the following command for that purpose:

```
git submodule foreach git checkout master
```

Answer (score 3):

For me all `git submodule` did **not** work. But this worked:

```
cd <path/to/submodule>
git pull
```

It downloads and thus updates the third party repo.
Then

```
cd <path/to/repo>
git commit -m "update latest version" <relative_path/to/submodule>
git push
```

which updates your remote repo (with the link to the last commit `repo@xxxxxx`).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an awesome one-liner to update everything to the latest on master:

```
git submodule foreach 'git fetch origin --tags; git checkout master; git pull' && git pull && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

[Thanks to Mark Jaquith](http://scribu.net/blog/git-alias-for-updating-submodules.html)

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way to handle git projects containing **submodules** is to always add

```
--recurse-submodules
```

at the end of each git command
example:

```
git fetch --recurse-submodules
```

another

```
git pull --update --recurse-submodules
```

etc...