# git: update submodule error

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

I am getting the following error when I am updating my sub module.

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: 8657febdb311a29253ef8e6a965e3c9089e36b00
Unable to checkout '8657febdb311a29253ef8e6a965e3c9089e36b00' in submodule path 'Fluent.Util'
```

I am kind of new to git and start using it recently. Can anyone help me with this. Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5828561/1734130

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2161389/1138252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague has set up the submodule incorrectly. The above posts does help.