# Git submodules: Is it possible to notify other developers of a change?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Say I fix a bug in a common submodule used by multiple projects.

Is there a way to automatically notify the developers of all the super-projects to update the submodule?

Comment: Well, you could add a hook, to send an email. There is no way to contact all the users of a repository through git itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a post-commit [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to send out emails.

You could get the email of all committers on the branch using (bash syntax)

```
git log --pretty:format="%ce" | sort | uniq
```

Or alternatively, enforce the developer to

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

to always be on the latest version of all submodules with every pull. May or may not be a good idea if there are breaking changes pushed, depending on how you want to enforce this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to automatically notify the developers of all the super-projects to update the submodule

No.
A submodule is a clone of an upstream repo, nested in a parent repo.
It is a *downstream* repo compared to the original repo you cloned as a submodule.

And in a distributed environment, you simply don't know of the downstream repos.
You only know of the upstream repo.
See "[Definition of “downstream” and “upstream”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166)".

As mentioned in "[Update git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5828396/6309)", you would need to go in the submodule and `git pull` directly in there in order to update said submodule.