# git submodules not consistently updating

Tags: git

My workplace recently switched to git and the powers that be set up components that are shared between projects as submodules, which causes widespread frustration among the people that are trying to figure out how to work with them.

After reading some Internet advice, I pull the project and submodules as follows:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule update --recursive --remote --init --merge
```

However, sometimes checking the status of the submodules gives me something like:

```
> git status
On branch feature
Your branch is behind 'origin/feature' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

which is resolved if I do

```
git submodule foreach git pull
```

I am at a loss.  Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21195182/6194839 maybe `git submodule update --remote --merge` or `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` would work? Maybe `git submodule --help` might point you on the correct path. My first instict is you might have a command `--recursive --remote --init --merge` that isn't doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: can you clarify why you think you're doing something wrong? submodules are not meant to update unless you tell them to.

Comment: @eis, I was under the impression that `git submodule update` will pull the latest from the submodules, which it apparently doesn't

Answer (score 2):

From a comment by OP:

> I was under the impression that git submodule update will pull the
> latest from the submodules, which it apparently doesn't

Indeed it does not. What it does is explained in for example [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

> **update**
>
> Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject expects by cloning missing submodules and updating the working tree of
> the submodules.
>
> **merge**
>
> the commit recorded in the superproject will be merged into the current branch in the submodule.

Superproject will always have a specific commit recorded about each of its submodules. An update command will use that commit and check it out - it won't actually update it to reference any new situation that project might have.

You're not doing anything wrong per se, that's the way it works. If you want to move the recorded commit to a latest one, you'll have to do it in another way. Doing it is better explained in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828324/update-git-submodule-to-latest-commit-on-origin?lq=1), but in short, doing `--remote` instead of `--merge` looks like the thing you're after.

Comment: I am doing `--remote` (see question), that's what confuses me.  Everything that I read, seems to imply that the commands are equivalent, but they don't behave so for me

Comment: @AlexO ah, just noticed that you're using both. Did you try leaving merge out?

Comment: Yes, it left me in "detached head" status on the submodules

Answer (score -2):

```
git pull origin yourbranch --recursive
cd submodulebrach
git checkout submodulebrach
cd ..
git commit -m submodule
git push origin yourbranch
```

Comment: I fail to see how it answers my question, can you please explain?

Comment: The question is asking how to update the local version of sub-modules cleanly. I don't understand why you want OP to push changes here.