# How to pull a new submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Tried looking for answers on this site and others:
[StackOverflow - Easy way pull latest of all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030169/easy-way-pull-latest-of-all-submodules#1032653)

They all seem to want to talk about if you are controlling them, not if someone else added one, and I just want to pull the additional one into my project without having to stash or backup my changes if I need to delete the folder.

Should I delete the `.gitmodules` file, and/or the submodule directories that I have already pulled down with `git clone --recursive`?
([StackOverflow - How to `git clone` including submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules))

These commands do not seem to help either:

- `git submodule update --init --recursive` seems like it did nothing.
- `git submodule update --recursive` nothing.
- `git fetch --recurse-submodules` output `Fetching submodule ...` several times.
- `git pull --recurse-submodules` output the same thing, and then said `Already up-to-date.` after the fetch trial.  Strange since in either case my submodules were already downloaded.
- `git clone --recursive ...` **Not tried yet.**  I feel like would overwrite any changes I have made, in the Stash or otherwise.
- `git submodule update --recursive --remote` checked out a new commit SHA for one of the submodules.
- `git submodule update --recursive` checked out a new commit SHA for one of the submodules.  Could be the older, original commit level.
- `git submodule status` gives the appropriate SHA, version, and name information for each, while still lacking the one that I want.
- `git submodule foreach git pull origin master`
- `git submodule update` does nothing.

I have been double-checking the library directory manually each time to make sure whether the additional submodule appeared or not.

I want to avoid performing certain actions, unless they are not destructive to my current repository state containing code changes, and solves my problem, in case it is a command I have mentioned but did not run, or anyone else has another to try.

I could try some of these with more effort, but I think I want to stop messing with them for now, and since I have not found the answer to this issue after doing some online searching, maybe the hopeful and eventual answer would help others anyway.

Am I suffering from the con mentioned here at all?
[Software Engineering - Git submodule vs Git clone](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189508/git-submodule-vs-git-clone)

More links:

- [StackOverflow - Update Git submodule to latest commit on origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828324/update-git-submodule-to-latest-commit-on-origin?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for listing all the possibilities. `git fetch --recurse-submodules` did work for me.

Comment: You knw what, I am reading your question and now I see it is contra-intuitive. Which why you may want to consider creating new issue ticket for git team. I guess pull must automatically process submodules appear/disappear.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When you want to pull a specific new module, you can use the following command:

```
git submodule update --init local/path/to/submodule/folder
```

If you wish to initialize all new submodules however. you can omit the path to the folder like so:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to run one command and get all new sub-module auto-initialized if still empty?

Comment: `git submodule update --init` (without specifying the folder path) seems to pull all new sub-modules

Answer (score 11):

You have to do two things:

1. Do `git pull` in your main repository which holds the submodules. This will add the new submodule as an empty directory.
2. Do `git submodule update --recursive --remote` in the main repository. This will pull the latest changes for all submodules, including the new one.

This works at least in Git 2.13. Also note that if the repositories and submodules are on GitHub, you have to make sure you have access rights to them (if they are private).

Comment: Works well for me! Only note is that it doesn't only pull a _new_ submodule, it updates all submodules. Also, I think for GitHub, you only need access rights if you use `git@github.com:user/repo`. If you use `https://github.com/user/repo` you don't need ssh access.

Comment: @CodyReichert I tried that and it didn't do anything for me on Ubuntu 16.04. The folders of new submodules remain empty. I have git 2.7.4. Could it be that it was enhanced in newer versions?

Answer (score 4):

Best suggestion I have received so far is to run this command:

```
git submodule add <URL_to_submodule> <local_path_to_place_submodule>
```

So it looks to be what the other contributor would have done, that I would do again, even though it already exists in the remote.

I guess this doesn't technically update the `.gitmodules` file from the remote's data like what would be expected, but haven't found a way to do that yet.

Credit for the help goes to [@pandatrax](https://twitter.com/pandatrax).

**Update**

Before trying the `add` method, I tried 1 more idea that involved copying the `.gitmodules` file from the remote manually and trying any of the update commands, but sadly that approach did not work either.  It may have gone differently if I executed the commands in the root, since I was in a subfolder, but I doubt it.

Then I used the `add` method, which downloaded the dependency, but the `.gitmodules` file showed changes.  Once I set-up the GitHub remote and pulled from it after discarding that file, the project seems to be in a better state now, even syncing the commit SHAs for the updated module or 2, either since they matched, or it was overwritten.

Comment: Aaron's answer is much better than re-adding. You should accept his answer as the one. Although it doesn't work recursively, unfortunately.

Comment: no @AlexisWilke, he has point. if submodule update --init --recurse did not help then most likely this submodule itself was not comitted and needs to bew readded and commited

Answer (score 2):

This should work, as long as the new submodule is in the .gitmodules in remote

`git pull --recurse-submodules`

Comment: I tried that too, and it did nothing. The submodule directories remain empty. Could it be that if you do not include the `--recurse-submodules` the first time you do a `git pull` then it's in a state that prevents the recursion?

Answer (score 1):

It's solved for my submodules when I updated submodule using the following command:

```
git pull <URL_to_submodule_or_repository> <Name_of_branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

> not if someone else added one, and I just want to pull the additional one into my project without having to stash or backup my changes if I need to delete the folder.

This should work better with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022): when "[`git fetch --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dd9ff30dffdd03c579f4d867286dac3e46e05c8d/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L187)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---recurse-submodulesyes%7Con-demand%7Cno))</sup> grabbed submodule commits that would be needed to recursively check out newly fetched commits in the superproject, it only paid attention to submodules that are in the current checkout of the superproject.

> Git now does so for all submodules that have been run "[`git submodule init`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dd9ff30dffdd03c579f4d867286dac3e46e05c8d/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L95)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-init--ltpathgt82308203))</sup> on.

See [commit 5fff35d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5fff35d880df2bb4cfce032c54a95abadce3f881), [commit b90d9f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b90d9f7632d380d3f16197ae657ab57075acd1eb), [commit 5370b91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5370b91f3fae9d7a511e23142b55082200152cef), [commit 73bc90d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73bc90d7e19c471318e799624b6d4c6d449c655d), [commit 6e1e0c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e1e0c9959f1df4b8c5aafb69d149374720b26dc), [commit 1e5dd3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e5dd3a1114643ca43e3d83da4f5c44447f061ff), [commit 7c2f8cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c2f8cc58cc3648a0e1e4c76be15a09114b4d9dd), [commit d1d1572](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1d1572e75edfa901fd6ab836402f57ba2da27b4), [commit 6e94bd6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e94bd64f334b91fab0f06b44ad00fc34a068a8c), [commit f3117df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3117dfdd1a0e586066bb8963b43324f5dee9f90) (07 Mar 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dd9ff30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd9ff30dffdd03c579f4d867286dac3e46e05c8d), 25 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b90d9f7632d380d3f16197ae657ab57075acd1eb): fetch unpopulated, changed submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Glen Choo</sup>

> "[`git fetch --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b90d9f7632d380d3f16197ae657ab57075acd1eb/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L187)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---recurse-submodulesyes%7Con-demand%7Cno))</sup> only considers populated submodules (i.e.
> submodules that can be found by iterating the index), which makes "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b90d9f7632d380d3f16197ae657ab57075acd1eb/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> behave differently based on which commit is checked out.
> As a result, even if the user has initialized all submodules correctly, they may not fetch the necessary submodule commits, and commands like "[`git checkout --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b90d9f7632d380d3f16197ae657ab57075acd1eb/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L297)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---recurse-submodules))</sup> might fail.
>
> Teach "[`git fetch to`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b90d9f7632d380d3f16197ae657ab57075acd1eb/Documentation/git-fetch.txt#L236)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-to))</sup> fetch cloned, changed submodules regardless of whether they are populated.
> This is in addition to the current behavior of fetching populated submodules (which is always attempted regardless of what was fetched in the superproject, or even if nothing was fetched in the superproject).
>
> A submodule may be encountered multiple times (via the list of populated submodules or via the list of changed submodules).
> When this happens, "`git fetch`" only reads the 'populated copy' and ignores the 'changed copy'.
> Amend the `verify_fetch_result()` test helper so that we can assert on which 'copy' is being read.

`fetch-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b90d9f7632d380d3f16197ae657ab57075acd1eb/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L189-L205):

> submodules should be fetched too. When recursing through submodules,
> `git fetch` always attempts to fetch "changed" submodules, that is, a
> submodule that has commits that are referenced by a newly fetched
> superproject commit but are missing in the local submodule clone. A
> changed submodule can be fetched as long as it is present locally e.g.
> in `$GIT_DIR/modules/` (see linkgit:gitsubmodules[7]); if the upstream
> adds a new submodule, that submodule cannot be fetched until it is
> cloned e.g. by `git submodule update`.
>
> When set to 'on-demand', only changed submodules are fetched. When set
> to 'yes', all populated submodules are fetched and submodules that are
> both unpopulated and changed are fetched. When set to 'no', submodules
> are never fetched.
>
> When unspecified, this uses the value of `fetch.recurseSubmodules` if it
> is set (see [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)), defaulting to 'on-demand' if unset.
> When this option is used without any value, it defaults to 'yes'.

`git fetch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b90d9f7632d380d3f16197ae657ab57075acd1eb/Documentation/git-fetch.txt#L290-L293):

> Using --recurse-submodules can only fetch new commits in submodules that are
> present locally e.g. in `$GIT_DIR/modules/`. If the upstream adds a new
> submodule, that submodule cannot be fetched until it is cloned e.g. by `git submodule update`. This is expected to be fixed in a future Git version.