# Why submodules are not updated using GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY:recursive

Tags: gitlab-ci

I created a .gitmodules file in the root of MASTER's project:

```
[submodule "SLAVE"]
    path = SLAVE
    url = ../../my-group/SLAVE.git
```

Added to MASTER's .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

Triggered MASTER's CI pipeline.

As a result, no changes made in SLAVE project were applied while running MASTER's CI

Comment: It downloads the submodules. Git submodules don't update to latest by default.

Comment: @JakubKania, could you advise what should be done to have "slave" project updated during running "master's" CI?

Comment: Well, run an update manually in before_script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828324/update-git-submodule-to-latest-commit-on-origin/21195182 , though my advise would be to use proper dependency managment instead of git submodules

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS` to the .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
    GIT_SUBMODULE_UPDATE_FLAGS: --remote --merge
```