# git submodule checkout latest commit of different branch from respective remotes

Tags: git, git-submodules

My parent project has a couple of submodules added to it.

For deployment purposes, I want to checkout a specific branch eg `master`, `staging`, etc in each submodule and pull the latest commit of this branch in each submodule.

I've checked various answers on SO like the following:

- [Easy way to pull latest of all git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1030169/820410)
- [How can I specify a branch/tag when adding a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777854/820410)
- [Update Git submodule to latest commit on origin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5828324/820410)

But it's very much confusing as to what is the best practice in 2022. I've `git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)`

So far I've understood that this command can be used to fetch the latest commit (from their respective remotes) of the branch already mentioned in `.gitmodules` file.

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

But how exactly do I use the `-b` option in order to switch the branches in all submodules at the same time, for diff environments deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution that worked for me.

**Simple Solution**

```
git submodule foreach <command>
```

The above command will run  for each submodule.

So I ran the following 2 commands to checkout out desired branch and pull latest commit in each submodule

```
git submodule foreach git checkout -B staging origin/staging
git submodule foreach git pull --rebase
```

---

**Complex Solution**

The following command updated the target branch in the `.gitmodules` file

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<submodule_path>.branch <target_branch_name>
```

I used the following command for the batch update for all submodules

```
git submodule status | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs -I {} git config -f .gitmodules submodule.{}.branch master
```

Then the following command pulled(fetched & merged) the latest commits of the respective remotes of each submodule

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

`--merge` alternatives:

- **Omit** - ommitting `--merge` will do a hard reset to submodules' remote repo
- `--rebase` - this will rebase your local changes on top of the remote branch's latest commit of submodules