# Not able to get the Source Code from GIT repository

Tags: git

I am unable to get the code from GIT(Tortise GIT 1.8.3) repository, Kindly help me.

```
Auto-merging AgentConnectIntegrationLibrary
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in AgentConnectIntegrationLibrary
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
warning: Failed to merge submodule AgentConnectIntegrationLibrary (not checked out)

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (6630 ms @ 7/11/2017 8:03:30 PM)
```

Comment: you have to fix conflicts and then commit the result, the message said that. Chech out which files has conflict and solve them.

Answer (score 0):

Chec k form command line the git status output.

If this is about submodule, you can reset the submodule folder, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32581852/6309).

Then check again `git status` for seeing the right command to apply (if any) once the state is clean.